# Password check if statements

Tags: c, if-statement

How do I make a password check that prints out every error with the password? If there are no errors, it needs to return 0.

It works until I submit a password with an upper and lowercase letter. I have tried to do nested if statements, but I have not found a way to do it efficiently make it work. Any advice?

```
 int isSafePassword(char password[])
    {
            if((passwordIsLongEnough(password))!=0)
                printf("\nThis password is not long enough.");

            if((passwordContainsDigit(password))!=0)
                printf("\nThis password does not contain a digit!");

            if((passwordHasMixedCase(password))!=0)
                printf("\nThis password does not contain a mix of small/upper-case letters");

            else
                return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You want to check passwordIsLongEnough, and then regardless of the result, you want to check passwordContainsDigit and passwordHasMixedCase? In that case the code has to remember, in some way, the result of passwordIsLongEnough, by storing it in some sort of state.

Comment: 1. If this is for a real project, not homework or something: a lot of password checks you can do actually make things less secure; the more restrictions you place on the password the less likely a random one from a password manager will work. Be very careful with handling passwords!

Comment: 2. You don’t need to say `!= 0`; you can say `if(! passwordIsLongEnough(password)` etc. 3. We probably can’t answer without the seeing the definition of `passwordHasMixedCase` and know exactly what went wrong; please give a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and describe what *does* happen.

Comment: Complex, crazy password rules result in passwords people can't remember.  That means they **WILL** write them down, reuse passwords, and use patterns to make passwords easier to remember.  And that all combines to make complex password rules counterproductive.

Comment: Increment a counter for each error you come across. Or simply append each error message to an array as that error is encountered and then check the array length at the end.

Comment: Your function does not return the correct pass/fail value - take a look at the code. Aside: if you are *configuring* a password a detailed analysis is reasonable, but if the password is being used for access: the answer is **pass** or **fail** with no clues as to why.

Comment: @AndrewHenle or they use password managers, with long, complex, unique passwords. Passwords should die, of course, but while we have them I'm not sure that encouraging memorable passwords is the way to go. Unless they're long phrases.

Comment: You want to `and` them together with short-circuit, `isSafePassword() = IsLongEnough() && ContainsDigit() && HasMixedCase()`, you can do this by returning false if any of these are false. It would be helpful if we could see the other functions.

Comment: thank you for your answers this is just a homework assignment but thank you for your security concerns. 

I used the same if statements but I incremented an int by 1 if it did not pass a requirement and then returned the int at the end.